# Apple Notes isn't letting me zoom in when using separate window on macOS

Tags: macos, notes.app

When I'm writing a note in a popped out window (by double-clicking on the note in the list), the "zoom in/out/actual size" options in the view menu are disabled. Most of the view menu is disabled, but most of the options are about the list of notes or other things that aren't present when you're in a separate note window.

But zooming should be allowed, I want to change the text display size. I can zoom in when the note isn't popped out, and indeed it's zooming the note independent of anything else, including when I open other notes, so it is zooming the note and not the whole app or something.

Zooming in the main window is a fine workaround, but it seems like it should work in a popped out window too. Is this a bug? Is there another way that I'm missing?